# System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent.LaunchUrl' not found

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-ad-msal

Experiencing exception in Azure B2C Directory login by using MSAL Library on Android platform with the following two libraries when updated to latest version (26.1.0.1)

1. Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs (version 26.1.0.1)
2. Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (version 26.1.0.1)

Please download sample from the following Link:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal

Exception:

System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent.LaunchUrl' not found.

StackTrace:

MonoDroid( 7659): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
MonoDroid( 7659): System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent.LaunchUrl' not found.
MonoDroid( 7659):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnResume (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] :0 
MonoDroid( 7659):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) S
An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: Check that you have the targeted Android SDK versions installed

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.Identity.Client 1.1.1-preview0040 was updated day 05/01/2018

See: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/1.1.1-preview0040

Now works with all libraries in version 25+

Answer (score 0):

MSAL at this point in time relies on the device having the Chrome Browser or a browser that supports Chrome custom tabs. The device probably does not have support either of these things. To test if this is the issue, you can download the Chrome via APK or play store and see if it resolves the issue.

You can also submit a feature request to support other browsers on [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues) directly.